# Inlined styles from Angular component library not displaying

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have created a library containing some components for use in an Angular 4 application. Functionally, everything works as expected when I use components from the library in an application. The CSS styling from the components is not being applied though.

I compile the library with the Angular compiler (`ngc`) and have a build step where all templates and styles get inlined. An example of some output in the generated `.js` bundle:

```
AppComponent.decorators = [
    { type: Component, args: [{
                selector: "app",
                styles: ["h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { display: inline; } h1 { font-size: 24px; } h2 { font-size: 18px; } h3 { font-size: 14px; } h4 { font-size: 12px; } h5 { font-size: 10px; } h6 { font-size: 8px; } #placeholder { min-width: 100%; min-height: 100vh; height: 100vh; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; }"],
                encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
                template: "<router-outlet></router-outlet>"
            },] },
];
```

As you can see, the styles are inline here using the `styles` property. The styles that are shown there, are not applied though.

Does anyone know why this happens? I'm kind of clueless about this particular problem. I followed all the guidelines for creating Angular packages in the [Angular Package Format](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/edit#).

**Edit:**
I bootstrap the Angular application with the AppComponent from the example output above as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent as LibraryAppComponent, AppModule as LibraryAppModule } from '@myscope/library';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ LibraryAppModule ],
    bootstrap: [ LibraryAppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Maximus Unfortunately not. Still trying to figure out what causes the issue.

Comment: Can you share your library? Or minimal copy of it?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you need `:host /deep/`. [component styles guid](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#special-selectors)

Comment: Why so? I actually converted an existing Angular application into this library so we could more easily reuse components across projects. The styles were fine when it was still an application instead of a library. The structure didn't change in the conversion, the same component is still the bootstrap component. The only difference is that another application uses that component to bootstrap now.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove double quotes from styles and add backquote/acute and your styles will be applied see below:

Instead of this:

```
styles: ["h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { display: inline; } h1 { font-size: 24px; } h2 { font-size: 18px; } h3 { font-size: 14px; } h4 { font-size: 12px; } h5 { font-size: 10px; } h6 { font-size: 8px; } #placeholder { min-width: 100%; min-height: 100vh; height: 100vh; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; }"]
```

Replace it with backquote/acute:

```
styles: [`h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { display: inline; } h1 { font-size: 24px; } h2 { font-size: 18px; } h3 { font-size: 14px; } h4 { font-size: 12px; } h5 { font-size: 10px; } h6 { font-size: 8px; } #placeholder { min-width: 100%; min-height: 100vh; height: 100vh; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; }`]
```

Button is right below esc key in left  key with tilde:~ and acute:`

Comment: `ngc` seems to replace the backquotes with double quotes again when running `ngc` after inlining the resources. After `ngc` is looks like this:

    `AppComponent.decorators = [
        { type: Component, args: [{
                    selector: "app",
                    styles: ["div[data-width-unit=\"0\"] { font-weight: bold; } h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { display: inline; }"],
                    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
                    template: "<router-outlet></router-outlet>"
                },] },
    ];`